# How to find the ratio of height/radius such that surface area of a cone is minimized?

Tags: calculus, volume

I know that the extrema should be taken at the derivative of $V$, where
$${V=\frac{\pi}{3}\cdot r^2\cdot h}$$. But I could only find where it maximizes. That's at h/r is equal to 2.

Comment: The surface area of a cone is given by $$A=\pi r(r+\sqrt{h^2+r^2})$$, What else is given?

Comment: Nothing else is given. 
It is asked to find the ratio that makes the surface area of the cone with minimized.

Comment: is it assumed to be under a constraint or something? For example, for a fixed volume, minimize the surface area? As that would make sense, and as far as I can tell, the question you asked cannot be solved without more information...

Comment: I've asked about it more and what @Hiten said was correct. The volume is supposed to be constant. That part has slipped

Comment: just to close the question, if my answer satisfies you, can you please select is as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Value and Derivative vs. Aspect Ratio of Cone enclosing unit volume]Among all right circular cones of volume $V$, we seek the aspect ratio $\displaystyle{x = \dfrac{h}{r}}$ such that the the total enclosing area, $A$, is minimized.

$V = \dfrac{\pi x r^3 }{3} \longrightarrow r = \left(\dfrac{3 V}{\pi x}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{3}}$

Let $s = \sqrt{r^2+h^2} = r\sqrt{1+x^2}$

Then the area can be expressed in terms of $x$: $$A = \pi r (r + s) = \pi r^2 \big(1 + \sqrt{1+x^2}\big) = \pi \left(\frac{3 V}{\pi x}\right)^{\dfrac{2}{3}} \big(1 + \sqrt{1+x^2}\big)$$

To minimize the area, we need to solve $\dfrac{dA}{dx} = 0$.

$$\therefore \dfrac{dA}{dx} = -\frac{2}{3}\large\big(\small x^{\small\cfrac{-5}{3}}\large\big)\small
\cdot\big(1 + \sqrt{1+x^2}\big) + 
\frac{x^{\cfrac{1}{3}}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = 0$$

Simplifying the expression, we obtain:

$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} - 
\dfrac{2}{3}\big(1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2} \big) = 0$$

Credits to Boojum for evaluating the solution: $\displaystyle{x = \dfrac{h}{r} = 2\sqrt{2}}$

Noteworthy points:

The height of the minimal-area cone equals the diagonal of a square enclosing its base.

We could set $V = 1$ without loss of generality.

If the base (included in the area) is a disk of radius $r$, the element (side) length is $s = 3r$.

With apex half-angle $\theta =$ arcsin ${r/s}$, the conical part would be cut from a disk of radius $3r$ with central angle $2\pi$ sin $\theta = 360° * r/s = 120°$.

Comment: How do you prove that it has no solution?

Comment: While I agree with your expression for the surface area $ \ A \ $ as a function of $ \ x \ = \ \frac{h}{r} \ \ , \ $ you may wish to check your input to the plotter for the graph.  The surface area has a quite distinct minimum value, but no _maximum_.  (OP found a critical point [wrong value], then mischaracterizes it as a maximum area.)

Comment: Fair question. If I could prove it readily, I would be a mathematician instead of an engineer. But I’m convinced there is no extremum to that function, based on the way the graph looks between 0.1 and 10. It’s counterintuitive initially, but the area increases without bound as the cone spreads toward a vast disk (h/r = x—>0), and vanishes asymptotically as it spikes into a ray (x—> ∞). I challenge anyone to find any positive real number $x$ at which the derivative (the right-hand side of the last equation in my reply) is negative.

Comment: The right-hand side of your last equation _does_ equal zero for $ \ x^2 \ = \ 8 \ \ , \ $ which identifies that the minimum area for the cone of constant volume occurs at $ \ x \ = \ 2\sqrt2 \ \ $ (we reject the result $ \ x \ = \ -2\sqrt2 \ \ ) \ . \    $  Your graph does not appear to represent the function on the right side of that equation.

Comment: You are correct, thank you! 
Easy to check in my head.

Comment: OK, glad this was sorted out.  (I spent many, _many_ (miserable) hours debugging code back in the day, so I can understand how things like this can happen...)

Comment: Lesson learned: Don’t trust (homebrew) tools to do your thinking for you. 

Comment: @Thricethinker: This answer has already undergone 14 revisions. This is a bit much: every edit bumps a post to the top of the main page of the site, so your answer has been bumped 14 times, eating up the "real estate" that other posts could have benefitted from. This will end up annoying the other users. Please consider making fewer edits, for instance by collecting several of them into a single one. Even better, try to solve a problem on paper completely before posting, such that there should be no reason for further editing. Thank you.

Comment: It finally occurred to me that there’ could be such a downside to overworking it, beyond wasting my own time. It’s done. Thanks for making the costs clear to me.

Comment: How I got it wrong initially (prompting me to look online for a prior “discovery” of my counterintuitive result that there was no optimal cone): The area function in my Python graphing script (lazily) used “2/3” instead of “2.0/3.0”  and 2/3 evaluates to 0 in Python (defaulting to integer division).

Answer (score 0):

you can write the formula for $V$ as:
$${V = \pi\frac{r^2h}{3}}$$
Differentiate with regards to $r$ to get:
$${0 = \frac{\pi}{3} (2rh + r^2\frac{dh}{dr}) \implies \frac{dh}{dr} = \frac{-2h}{r}}$$
Remember this as eqn 1.

Similarly, differentiate the formula of Surface area with regards to $r$ to get:
$${\frac{dA}{dr} = \pi(r+\sqrt{h^2+r^2}) + \pi r[1 + (2r + 2h\frac{dh}{dr})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{h^2+r^2}}] = 0}$$
$${\implies r + \sqrt{h^2+r^2} + r[1 + (2r + 2h\frac{dh}{dr})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{h^2+r^2}}] = 0]}$$
$${\implies \sqrt{h^2+r^2} + r\cdot(2r + 2h\frac{dh}{dr})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{h^2+r^2}} = 0}$$
Let this be eqn 2.

Substitute the value of $\frac{dh}{dr}$ from eqn one to get the ratio of $\frac{h}{r}$.

Differentiate eqn 2 again to see if it is a minima or a maxima.